# Осмысленный код на C без кавычек

Tags: c

Как написать код на `C` без точек с запятой. Например, программу выводящую строчку?

Comment: @something Не меняйте, пожалуйста, смысл вопроса после данного ответа.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const char str[] = {65, 9, 66, 0};
char *ptr = str;   
while (*ptr) putchar(*ptr++);
```

Написал. Как платить будете?